# Port-forwarding to a local domain using socat

Tags: networking, port, socat

I'm trying to setup port forwarding from localhost to a local server using socat. The server is available via `http://my-local-domain`.

Here is what I tried:

```
socat -d -d tcp-listen:8081,reuseaddr,fork tcp:my-local-domain:80
```

When I open the browser and go to `http://localhost:8081`, I see my original localhost page, not the page when I navigate to my-local-domain.

How does one create port-forwarding to a local domain using socat?

Comment: I don't get  the issue... I have launched a server at localhost:8000, and I added alias `127.0.0.1  fancydomain.com`. I spawned`socat -d -d tcp-listen:8081,reuseaddr,fork tcp:fancydomain.com:8000`. Accessing `fancydomain.com` in browser gives back the correct webpage from my local server. am I missing something?

Comment: @dgan From my understanding, if it works you should be able to access `fancydomain.com` by putting `localhost:8081` in the browser.

Comment: I confirm I am able to access web page with `localhost:8081` through a browser and/or `curl`

Comment: Are you on Mac OS X?

Comment: I am on LInux Debian Buster

Comment: Ok. I seemed to have homed it down to an nginx config issue. When I set the local domain to listen for another port [say 8000], and then do `socat -d -d tcp-listen:8081,reuseaddr,fork tcp:my-local-domain:8000` it works. But it doesn't work for port 80, not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I'm not able to use Port 80 because the Host appears as `localhost` to NGINX, and so `localhost` serves the request [which would explain the original issue].

You can verify this by:

1. Opening `nginx.conf`
2. Adding `..."Host=$host"...` to the log_format
3. `Tailing` the access logs [`tail -f /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log`]

You'll notice that Host is always `localhost`, and so localhost serves the request.

The way to solve this is to change the Host info from `localhost` to `my-local-server`:

```
Localhost:8081 --> [change Host info] --> my-local-server:80
```

The way I found to do this was to create a proxy via Node.JS [as a go-between] as follows:

- Create `proxy.js`
- Copy the contents of [the code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andris9/8093905/raw/c4e373d158edbc5fbcf430dea3eb387c68880d5e/change_origin_proxy.js) from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andris9/8093905#file-change_origin_proxy-js) and paste into `proxy.js`
- Run the following command in the terminal to create proxy to web server:

```
PORT_LISTEN=8091 PORT_TARGET=80 HOST_TARGET="my-local-server" HOST_ORIGIN="my-local-server" node proxy.js
```

- Run socat to proxy

```
socat -d -d tcp-listen:8081,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8091
```

So now we have the following:

```
Localhost:8081 --> Localhost:8091 --> my-local-server:80
```

This is what worked.